ADF Filter activity: the sequence of output
In ADF, will Filter activity retain the sequence of items in array or it can shuffle the sequence to some degree or at some scenarios?
For example, the array is (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), the condition is that item is not multiple of two. I will assume the output will always be (1,3,5,7,9), but can it be possible that the output becomes (3,7,1,5,9) or any other sequence?
Thanks.
I have already searched ADF documentation, but I cannot find anything related to this. I tried run several times, looks like the sequence retains the same as input, but I am not sure whether this is always the case.

Not sure, but I don't think this should be tagged with oracle-adf. Also, it would help the community help you if you provided details about your specific application.

My specific application is to find the first one among those that satisfy the filter condition.
